# @ViewChild es Undefined

Tags: angular, viewchild

Tengo una vista que se renderiza depues que un observable emite su valor en la vista tengo una referencia la cual accedo con viewChild en el .ts pero es undefined en el afterViewInit y es porque el observable emite su valor despues de unos 2 segundos susede que antes que el observable emita ya se ejecuto el siclo de vida afterViewInit por lo que la referencia viewChild es undefined. Como obtengo la referencia viewChild?

TypeScript:

```
...
  
  data$ = of([
    { id: 1, name: 'same1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'same2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'same3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'same4' },
  ]);
  view!: any[];
  
  @ViewChild('render')
  render!: ElementRef;
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data$.pipe(delay(2000)).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.view = res;
    });
  }
  
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.render, 'get undefined here');
  }
  ...
```

El HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="view; else loader">
  <p #render>Render view</p>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loader></ng-template>
```